# Alternative to Direct X for Video Capturing On Windows 8

Tags: c#

I have C Static Library for Capturing Video from Camera.It uses Direct X to Interface Camera.

I wanted to create API in .Net C# for Capturing Video and do not want to use DirectX. The Target OS is Windows 8.Api Should be in Such way it should work on Both Desktop and Metro Mode of the Windows 8.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Windows 8 Metro is all about DirectX - any reason you don't want to use it ?

Comment: @Yahia But Metro Deos not support Win32. So will that be any effect.My Existing C Library uses DirectX So Can I continue with the C Library On Windows.

Comment: Metro is built upon Win32 which is packaged as WinRT... at BUILD they specifically had sessions about DirectX in Metro... do you need links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above:

DirectX is at the heart of Windows 8 / Metro...

Several sessions on DirectX in Metro were held at BUILD - see http://www.buildwindows.com/Sessions/Tagged/DirectX

Regarding DirectX in Metro see for example http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-766T

As the whole API (WinRT etc.) is not final right now it is sure not easy to port your code right now but from what I understand it will possible...

Another point: the Metro API is packaged as WinRT which is COM with several new aspects... this API is usable from .NET + native code (like C/C++)!

Comment: Please Confirm My Guess.....  Win32 Specific Api might not work on Metro.So I might have to replace C++ Win32 Code with C++ WinRT Code Keeping DirectX Api Call Intact.

Comment: Yes - from what I understand you will have to port/change your library to use the new WinRT based API... technically it might be possible to use the "old API" but it is far too early to tell whether this is possible/stable/supported...